# C# Can I use values from a form in other form?

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

Is there any chance to "include" a form in other form? I hope is not a stupid question but here's what I'm trying to do. I have a form which is called "index". In that form I have a login form with the following script for server connection:

```
private void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = "Server=localhost;Database=aplicatie;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";
                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong when trying to connect to database!");
            }
        }
```

Now, I have other form which is called "admin" and I added a button wherewith I want to disconnect from the server. Here's the code of the button from "admin" form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index i = new index();
        DialogResult dialres = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca vreti sa va deconectati?", "Atentie!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialres == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                i.connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection has been closed.");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A form is just a class, like any other class.  If you provide a public property in your form class, for example, you can access it in the same way you would a property in any other class.

```
var myForm = new SomeFormClass();
myForm.MyProperty = "Foo";

var myControl = Form.Controls["SomeControl"];
myControl.Text = "Some Text";
```

...etc.

Comment: I know that, I tried to make it public but it didn't worked..I feel like something's missing..

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Specify the behavior you actually expect, and the behavior you're actually getting, in your question.

Comment: You lost me..you said that the answer is in my question?

Comment: Tell us what you wanted the code to do, and then tell us what the code actually did.  Tell us that in your question.  Include any error messages you are getting.  "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about your problem.

Comment: Well? Don't you understand what I want to do?

Comment: You need to pass your `context` into the second form.  There are a number of ways to do that.  One way is to create a constructor in your form class that accepts a connection parameter.

Comment: That means there's no object instance in your object variable.  Usually, you `new MyClass` first.

Comment: `index i = new index();` is not an instance?

Comment: It's likely that the problem is occurring somewhere else.